# AG Grid could not find matching row model for rowModelType serverSide

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I created an angular component to show ag-grid data with server-side `rowModelType`. I am following this link: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/server-side-model-datasource/.

**But getting two errors:**
[image]

Here is my component and module structure:

**OrganizationsComponent.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//declare function organizations_ag_Grid(): any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-organizations',
  template: `<ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    id="myGrid"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [rowModelType]="rowModelType"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  ></ag-grid-angular>`,
  styleUrls: ['./organizations.component.css'],
})
export class OrganizationsComponent implements OnInit {
  public gridApi;
  public gridColumnApi;

  public columnDefs;
  public defaultColDef;
  public rowModelType;
  public rowData;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        field: 'athlete',
        minWidth: 220,
      },
      {
        field: 'country',
        minWidth: 200,
      },
      { field: 'year' },
      {
        field: 'sport',
        minWidth: 200,
      },
      { field: 'gold' },
      { field: 'silver' },
      { field: 'bronze' },
    ];
    this.defaultColDef = {
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 100,
    };
    this.rowModelType = 'serverSide';
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //organizations_ag_Grid();
  }

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    //this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    this.http
      .get('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json')
      .subscribe((data) => {
        var fakeServer = createFakeServer(data);
        var datasource = createServerSideDatasource(fakeServer);
        params.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
      });
  }
}

function createServerSideDatasource(server) {
  return {
    getRows: function (params) {
      console.log('[Datasource] - rows requested by grid: ', params.request);
      var response = server.getData(params.request);
      setTimeout(function () {
        if (response.success) {
          params.success({ rowData: response.rows });
        } else {
          params.fail();
        }
      }, 500);
    },
  };
}
function createFakeServer(allData) {
  return {
    getData: function (request) {
      var requestedRows = allData.slice();
      return {
        success: true,
        rows: requestedRows,
      };
    },
  };
}
```

**OrganizationsModule.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { OrganizationsComponent } from './organizations.component';
import { OrganizationsRoutingModule } from './organizations-routing.module';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [OrganizationsComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    OrganizationsRoutingModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
  ],
})
export class OrganizationsModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `serverSide` row model type is part of the Enterprise package you need to add `ag-grid-enterprise` to your `package.json` dependencies and then add the following to your application code. This will enable all the enterprise features.

```
import `ag-grid-enterprise`;
```

See the documentation for setting up Enterprise features [here](https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/getting-started/#getting-started-with-ag-grid-enterprise-1).

Answer (score -1):

Server-side row model **only supports** for **AG-Grid enterprise** version.

"If you are using **AG Grid Community**, use **Client-Side Row Model**(load all your data into the browser), or **Infinite Row Model**(load it in blocks).

If you are using **AG Grid Enterprise**, use **Server-Side Row Model**.
"

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-models/